# Opencv assertion failed

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to extract from an image only the contours which have a specific size.

I process like this

```
int offsetX ;
int offsetY ;
//here: read original image as 8UC3 
cv::Mat original = cv::imread("0.png");
Mat imgx=original.clone();
cv::imshow("original", original);
cvtColor(imgx,imgx,CV_BGR2GRAY);
Mat thresh;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
RNG rng(12345);
vector < vector<Point> > contours; 
adaptiveThreshold(imgx, thresh, 255, 1, 1, 31, 2);
findContours(thresh, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(thresh.size(), CV_8UC3);
cout << "drawing "<<drawing.type()<<endl;
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(original.rows, original.cols, original.type());
image.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(255));
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    vector < Point > cnt = contours[i];
    if (contourArea(cnt) > 0)
    {
        Rect rec = boundingRect(cnt);
        if ((rec.height > 20 ) &&(3.5*rec.height>rec.width)&&  (rec.width>15)/*&& (rec.width<40)*/)
        {
            cout<<rec.x<<" "<<rec.y<<endl;
            offsetX=rec.x;
            offsetY=rec.y;
            Mat roi = original(rec);
            int width = roi.cols;
            int height = roi.rows;
            cout <<"h= "<<height<<" w= "<<width<<endl;
            cv::Rect characterLocation;
            if(height>35)
                characterLocation = cv::Rect(offsetX+3, offsetY, width, height);
            else
                characterLocation = cv::Rect(offsetX, offsetY, width, height);
            original(characterLocation).copyTo(image(characterLocation));
            imshow("jihedddd",roi); 
            imwrite("xxxxxx.png",roi);
            Mat stagedImage;
            Mat img;
            Scalar color = Scalar(255, 255, 255);
            drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
            imshow("Contours", drawing);
            waitKey();
            GaussianBlur(stagedImage, img, Size(5, 5), 2, 2);
            medianBlur(img, stagedImage, 3);
            Mat copy = original.clone();
            rectangle(copy, Point(rec.x, rec.y),
            Point(rec.x + rec.width, rec.y + rec.height),
            CV_RGB(0x00,0x00,0xff), 3);
            cv::imshow("char copied", image);
        }
    }
}
medianBlur(image,image,3);
cv::imshow("char copied", image);
cv::imwrite("characterC_result.tiff ", image);
cv::waitKey();
```

But when I run this code I have an error

> opencv  error :assertion failed

This is an example of [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0o0hqjvqc7t55cj/0.png?dl=0) which give me the error.

Comment: Have you stepped through it to see where it errors?

Comment: I think it is here the error original(characterLocation).copyTo(image(characterLocation)); but i still don't know the cause of it

Comment: You are going to have to debug the code to figure out what is the exact line of code that causes this problem. We can't help without that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to be careful with this:

```
characterLocation = cv::Rect(offsetX+3, offsetY, width, height);
```

if width is the imagewidth, you are out of bounds here. you either have to subtract x from width, or crop the rect to the image borders:

```
// get the Rect for the original image:
cv::Rect borders(Point(0,0), image.size());

// crop to the legal size:
characterLocation = cv::Rect(offsetX+3, offsetY, width, height) & borders;
```